# Network (Ethernet, Wifi) man in the middle bridge setup (DHCP, DNS)

Tags: networking, wireless, dns, ethernet, dhcp

I want to analyze network traffic of a device "under test" (DUT) with Ethernet and Wifi and redirect some requests using a local DNS to a local server.

Setup: `Ubuntu 22.04 <-> Switch <-> Router/Modem <-> Internet`

I have two USB interfaces, Ethernet and Wifi.

Using Ubuntu's System menu or Network Settings, I can easily

- create a Wifi Hotspot
- use the Ethernet in "Shared to other computers" mode.

The respective interface then has access to the internet and can be sniffed with wireshark.

What do I need to do to run DHCP and DNS (pass-through all except a few domains that are to be redirected to a local port) on the USB interfaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the interface's IP address (in Hotspot mode I can't seem to find the GUI showing the interface properties, so `$ ip addr show`), here 10.42.0.1.

The simplest way to "catch" and direct a domain name system-wide is to add an entry into `/etc/hosts`, e.g.

```
10.42.0.1 sub.domain.tld
```

This lookup is managed by `/etc/nsswitch.conf` before DNS (which in turn seems to be handled by resolved, see `resolvectl status` and `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`).

For a quick test, running
`sudo python3 -m http.server 80 --bind 10.42.0.1` will list the CWD at http://localhost.

This may already be all I need. For further "research":

- the network settings GUI also allows setup of a "bridge" connection.
- for installing a DNS, `dnsmasq` and `bind9` came up in a quick search.

Comment: I needed to restart the Wifi Hotspot for changes in hosts to take effect